# Formatting Table with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I can't figure out how to format my table so that there is a header for each section of attributes. I only see one header when there are actually more that I need to see.

For example I'm able to get DROID 4 by MOTOROLA and all of it's attributes go from Full Retail Price to Voice Dialing. After Voice Dialing there should be a second header for another phone. Clearly my logic is messed up and I have been struggling for about 4 hours on it. I also need the two tables to be side by side, not in a long list like this.

[image]

This is what I'm trying to achieve:[image]

My code looks like this:

```
<?
session_start();
if(!session_is_registered(myusername)){
header("location:main_login.php");
}
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
<?php

include_once 'config.php';

$conf = new config();

mysql_connect($conf->getdbServ(), $conf->getdbUser(), $conf->getdbPwd()) or die(mysql_error()); 
 mysql_select_db($conf->getDB()) or die(mysql_error());



 $selectedPhones = $_POST['phones'];


 $totalSelected = count($selectedPhones);
 //echo $totalSelected;
 $idList = "";
 for($i=0;$i < $totalSelected; $i++){
         $idList .= $selectedPhones[$i] . ",";
     }
 $idList = substr($idList,0,-1);


    $query = "Select name from ".$conf->getproductTbl()." WHERE id='$idList'";
    $res=mysql_query($query);



 //echo $idList;

 $data  = mysql_query("SELECT ".$conf->getproductTbl().".id,   ".$conf->getproductAttr().".* from ".$conf->getproductTbl()."
                       LEFT JOIN ".$conf->getproductAttr()." ON   ".$conf->getproductTbl().".id=".$conf->getproductAttr().".prodFK
                     Where ".$conf->getproductTbl().".id IN(" . $idList . ");");

echo "<table width = 100% border = '1' cellspacing = '2' cellpadding = '0'>";

while ($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
{
    echo "<th colspan='2'>".$result["name"]."</th>";
}
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($data)) {
    echo "<tr><td>";
    echo $row["Name"];
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo $row["value"];
    echo "</td></tr>";
}   

echo "</table>";

 ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

1 - You might want to look into MYSQL JOIN to combine your two queries. (http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqljoins.php)

2 - Use CSS to style your result set.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this.. I hope that will help you.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <?php
        for($i=0;$i < $totalSelected; $i++){
        //$idList .= $selectedPhones[$i] . ",";
        ?>
        <td><?php
        $data  = mysql_query("SELECT ".$conf->getproductTbl().".id,   ".$conf->getproductAttr().".* from ".$conf->getproductTbl()."
        LEFT JOIN ".$conf->getproductAttr()." ON   ".$conf->getproductTbl().".id=".$conf->getproductAttr().".prodFK
        Where ".$conf->getproductTbl().".id = ".$selectedPhones[$i]);

        echo "<table width = 100% border = '1' cellspacing = '2' cellpadding = '0'>";

        while ($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
        {
            echo "<th colspan='2'>".$result["name"]."</th>";
        }
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($data)) {
            echo "<tr><td>";
            echo $row["Name"];
            echo "</td><td>";
            echo $row["value"];
            echo "</td></tr>";
        }   

        echo "</table>";

        ?>
        </td>
        <?php }?>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This produced the above result. Nothing was changed.